# File transfers very slow in one direction

Tags: ssh, openvpn, rsync, scp, iperf

I am having trouble debugging a connection issue :

- Server A (OMV) has a fast internet connection : 900mbps down / 600 mbps up
- Client B (Windows 10 using wsl) has a decent internet connection : 900mbps down / 300 mbps up

I have set up an openvpn (same with wireguard) tunnel between A and B.
RSYNC / SCP / FTP transfers through openvpn tunnel from B to A are **very slow**
MTU is set to 1500 on both sides

iperf results are :

- A->B : 100Mbps
- B->A : **10Mbps**

HTTP call through VPN :

- B->A **10 Mbps**

HTTPS call through internet :

- A->B 300 Mbps
- B->A **10Mbps**

Notice the **10Mbps** threshold when A is receiving, through VPN or internet.
I think I got this slow http call related problem before and I had to tweak something with the eth interface but I am not sure about it. Also, why would it work well while torrenting..

I first though it was an encryption-related problem, as A only has a Pentium J5005 and B has a 5900x **however, while torrenting on A (A is a seedbox), I can get as up as 300-400 Mbps**

One last thing, every service is container-ized on A :
openvpn, wireguard, reverse proxy, torrent client

scp and rsync were executed from B.
ftp (get) was executed from A.
No sign of CPU / MEMORY high usage on the server

Thank you very much for any hint you would give me

Comment: What kind of encryption do you use on the tunnel? Keep in mind that your are double encrypting it, because WireGuard probably encrypts the traffic that goes over the tunnel, and scp uses it own encryption. Do you have the same issues when you use a ssh tunnel for example? Can you please add the configuration of the tunnels to your post.

Comment: I don't think it is that important since I also did some direct-https calls (so only one encryption)

Comment: Ok how can we help you then if we don't have all the information?

Comment: What's the tunnel MTU?

Comment: @Turdie I am sorry but except for the encryption protocols, I pretty much already asked in the main post these questions ; also you edited your comment after mine. I will post about the tunnel configuration soon. Thank you

Comment: As mentioned in the post, MTU is 1500 on both sides

Comment: Openvpn info : Cypher AES-256-CBC, Auth SHA256

Comment: Also, I might have omitted some information and that is the reason why I am posting ; there might be some criteria that I didn't think about

Comment: Is tunnel mtu 1500 bytes? That's not a good idea, as you're encapsulating it. Try tunnel mtu of 1400 bytes.

Comment: Also check the compression of the tunnel and try different configurations.

Comment: Cypher AES-256-CBC, Auth SHA256 is quite an heavy one try 128

Comment: I will try to get the time to do this tomorrow, thank you

Comment: Changing MTU to 1400 didn't change anything

Comment: I just tried an scp over the internet, opening temporary my ssh port
--> 2Mb/s, so still bad

Comment: I have good news :  
I've set up an ubuntu virtual machine on B machine.. and it looks like it is working fine. Through windows' powershell, it is fine too. Which means.. WSL is slowing the transfer